# Как создать сетевой диск в ubuntu через через samba?

Tags: samba, ubuntu, linux

Как создать сетевой диск в ubuntu через через samba?

Сетевой диск должен быть доступен в windows.

Comment: @Родион Преображенский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Как бы какой вопрос такой ответ. Правой кнопкой на папке которую надо сдлать доступной. Там на вкладке "Общедоступная папка локальной сети" ставим соответсвующие галочки и готово. Samba делает сетевую папку а виндовс ее с удовольствием видет.

Answer (score 0):

Путем редактирования файла `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Comment: @gurzufnet, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.